# How can I execute and schedule Databricks notebook from Azure Devops Pipeline using YAML

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-databricks, azure-devops-rest-api, cicd

I wanted to do CICD of my azure Databricks notebook using YAML file.
I have followed the below flow

1. Pushed my code from Databricks notebook to Azure Repos.
2. Created a Build using below YAML script.

```
stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build stage

  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    steps:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to:  $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        TargetFolder: ' $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish Artifact: notebooks'
      inputs:
        ArtifactName: dev_release
    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
        ArtifactName: 'publish build'
        publishLocation: 'Container'
```

By doing above I was able to create a Artifact.

Now I have added another task to deploy that artifact to my Databricks workspace. By using below YAML Script.

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy stage

  jobs:
  - job: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
    steps:
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      inputs:
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        artifactName: 'dev_release'
        downloadPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'
    - task: databricksDeployScripts@0
      inputs:
        authMethod: 'bearer'
        bearerToken: 'dapj0ee865674cd9tfb583dbad61b78ce9b1-4'
        region: 'Central US'
        localPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
        databricksPath: '/Shared'
```

Now i want to run the deployed notebook from here only. So I have "Configure Databricks CLI" task and "Execute Databricks" task to execute the note book.

**Got below Error**:
##[error]Error: Unable to locate executable file: 'databricks'. Please verify either the file path exists or the file can be found within a directory specified by the PATH environment variable. Also verify the file has a valid extension for an executable file.
##[error]The given notebook does not exist.

How can I execute notebook from Azure DevOps. My notebooks are in Scala Language.
**Is there any other way to use in Production servers.**

Answer (score 0):

As you have deployed the Databricks Notebook using Azure DevOps and asking for any other way to run it, I would like to suggest you **Azure Data Factory Service.**

In Azure Data Factory, you can create pipeline that executes a Databricks notebook against the Databricks jobs cluster. You can also pass Azure Data Factory parameters to the Databricks notebook during execution.

Follow the official tutorial to [Run Databricks Notebook with Databricks Notebook Activity in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook) to deploy and run Databrick Notebook.

Additionally, you can schedule the pipeline trigger at any particular time or event to make the process completely automatic. Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipeline-execution-triggers

Comment: Thanks for answering @UtkarshPal-MT. But my requirement is to run notebook from Azure DevOps itself. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```yaml
- job: job_name          
  displayName: test job
  pool:
    name: agent_name(selfhostedagent)
    #pool:
  workspace:
    clean: all    
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
    displayName: 'Download Build Artifacts'
    inputs:
      artifactName: app
      downloadPath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
  - task: riserrad.azdo-databricks.azdo-databricks-configuredatabricks.configuredatabricks@0
    displayName: 'Configure Databricks CLI'
    inputs:
      url: '$(Databricks_URL)'
      token: '$(Databricks_PAT)'
  - task: riserrad.azdo-databricks.azdo-databricks-deploynotebooks.deploynotebooks@0
    displayName: 'Deploy Notebooks to Workspace'
    inputs:
      notebooksFolderPath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/app/path/to/notebbok'
      workspaceFolder: /Shared
  - task: riserrad.azdo-databricks.azdo-databricks-executenotebook.executenotebook@0
    displayName: 'Execute /Shared/path/to/notebook'
    inputs:
      notebookPath: '/Shared/path/to/notebook'
      existingClusterId: '$(cluster_id)'
```